# Raycasts In Unity Not Detecting Enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I've been trying to set up raycasts for a pistol to shoot in Unity, and they will not detect any enemy rigidbodies or deduct health. The enemies are all on a whatIsEnemy layer and have the Tag "Enemy".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting.Antlr3.Runtime.Tree;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.VFX;

public class RaycastShootPistol : MonoBehaviour
{
    LineRenderer laserLine;

    public int gunDamage = 1;
    public float fireRate = .25f;
    public float weaponRange = 50f;
    public float reloadTime, timeBetweenShooting, timeBetweenShots;
    public float hitForce = 100f;
    public int magazineSize, bulletsPerTap, bulletsLeft;
    public bool allowButtonHold;
    public float spread =1;
    public int bulletsShot;

    //states
    bool shooting, readyToShoot, reloading;

    //References
    public VisualEffect pistolShootEffect;
    public RaycastHit hit;
    public Animator PistolAnimator;
    public Transform gunEnd;
    private Camera fpsCam;
    public LayerMask whatIsEnemy;



    //how long we want the laser to remain visible in the game view once the player has fired.
    private WaitForSeconds shotDuration = new WaitForSeconds(.07f);

    //nextFire will hold the time at which the player will be allowed to fire again after firing.
    private float nextFire;

    private void Awake()
    {
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        readyToShoot= true;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Test");
        pistolShootEffect = GameObject.Find("MuzzleFlashPistol").GetComponent<VisualEffect>();
        PistolAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        laserLine = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        gunEnd = GameObject.Find("GunEnd").GetComponent<Transform>();
        fpsCam = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GunInputs();
    }

    private IEnumerator ShotEffect()
    {
        // Play the shooting sound effect
        // laserLine.enabled = true;
        yield return shotDuration;
        laserLine.enabled = false;
    }
    private void GunInputs()

    {
        //buttons
        if (allowButtonHold) shooting = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        else shooting = Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && bulletsLeft < magazineSize && !reloading) Reload();
       
        

            //shoot
            if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft > 0)
            {
              bulletsShot = bulletsPerTap;
                Shoot();
            }
        
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            // Start our ShotEffect coroutine to turn our laser line on and off
          
         
        

    }
    private void Reload()
    {
        PistolAnimator.SetTrigger("ReloadPressed");
        Invoke("ReloadFinished", reloadTime);
    }
    private void ReloadFinished()
    {
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
    }
    private void Shoot()
    {
        readyToShoot = false;

        //For Greater Spread while running if(rigidbodt.velocity.magnitude > 0) {spread = soread * 1.5;} else spread = "normal spread";
        //Spread
        float x = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
        float y = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
        Vector3 direction = fpsCam.transform.forward + new Vector3(x, y, 0);
       

        


        PistolAnimator.SetTrigger("Shoot");

        // Create a vector at the center of our camera's viewport
        Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));
        // Declare a raycast hit to store information about what our raycast has hit (Declared earlier)

        // Set the start position for our visual effect for our laser to the position of gunEnd
        laserLine.SetPosition(0, gunEnd.position);

        // Check if our raycast has hit anything
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, direction, out hit, weaponRange, whatIsEnemy))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            ShootingAi target = hit.transform.GetComponent<ShootingAi>();
           
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name + "was hit ");
         
            
               target.TakeDamage(gunDamage);
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.GetComponent<ShootingAi>().enemyHealth);
            
            // St the end position for our laser line
            laserLine.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
            // Get a reference to a health script attached to the collider we hit
            ShootableBox health = hit.collider.GetComponent<ShootableBox>();
            // If there was a health script attached
            if (health != null)
            {
                // Call the damage function of that script, passing in our gunDamage variable
                health.Damage(gunDamage);
            }

            // Check if the object we hit has a rigidbody attached
            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                // Add force to the rigidbody we hit, in the direction from which it was hit
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * hitForce);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If we did not hit anything, set the end of the line to a position directly in front of the camera at the distance of weaponRange
            laserLine.SetPosition(1, rayOrigin + (fpsCam.transform.forward * weaponRange));
        }

        //Graphics
        pistolShootEffect.Play();
       
        StartCoroutine(ShotEffect());



        bulletsLeft--;
        bulletsShot--;

        Invoke("ResetShot", timeBetweenShooting);
        if (bulletsShot > 0 && bulletsLeft > 0)
            Invoke("Shoot", timeBetweenShots);

  

     
    }
    private void ResetShot()
    {
        readyToShoot = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the Shooting AI Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootingAi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int enemyHealth;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        enemyHealth -= damage;
        Debug.Log(enemyHealth);
    }
}
```

And the Shootable Box script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootableBox : MonoBehaviour
{

    //The box's current health point total
    public int currentHealth = 3;

    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        //subtract damage amount when Damage function is called
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;

        //Check if health has fallen below zero
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            //if health has fallen below zero, deactivate it 
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried manipulating the location of the raycast, setting the rigidbodies of the enemies to continuous, and more that I can't recall.

Comment: So change the raycast to hit all and see what it is hitting. This is not a minimal viable example.

Comment: Can you provide us with some logs, and some screenshots of your scene view? Have you tried reducing the weapon spread? Also, does your player have a `Rigidbody`? If it does, you might want to check if the raycast hits that `Rigidbody` instead of the enemy's `Rigidbody`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really new to Unity, but had the same problem in Urhosharp with the raycast not hitting all the time - using a spherecast (with small radius) worked much better.
Still, if you're not hitting anything ever, it is likely another problem.